# Can I cut an opening into the stringer of my staircase to create a doorway?

Tags: doors, structural, stairs, beam

I am remodeling an old house and am looking to add an additional bathroom that would be accessed through what is currently a storage space under the winder stair case. In order to create sufficient headheight for a doorway I would need to cut into the stringer of the staircase. I was wondering if anyone here knows whether this is possible? I am hoping I might be able to insert a thin steel beam or create some other way of supporting the weight/structure of the staircase, whilst still cutting the opening to allow for a door to be inserted.

Here's a picture of the staircase and current storage cupboard:

[image]

And here's a close-up of the area I'd like to cut. Taped in green here is the area I'd need to cut/remove to create the new door.

[image]

All the other options for the layout are suboptimal so very keen to make this work. Unfortunately not able to replace the whole staircase either so this is really the only option. Any thoughts?

Comment: It should be possible, but will need to add equal or greater support to the stairs.  A structural engineer will give the best advice as to what is needed.  Not fun when using the bathroom, someone walking the stairs drops in to visit.

Comment: @crip659 — that’s pretty much the whole answer right there.